# Utilizing amazon gpu cluster in web app

Tags: amazon-web-services, cuda, gpu

Does anyone have any experience plugging into an Amazon gpu cluster in a web app? Is it even possible? I want to make an online interface to a simulator I have written in cuda, but everything I have seen so far involves ssh and the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very possible!

You may want to consider binding your CUDA C code (I'm just assuming C) to your preferred scripting language for better efficiency if you intend to build the front end logic *not* in a lower level programming language but absolutely this is possible.

Keep in mind, many web developers build their apps strictly from the command line, you simply need to find an effective and efficient way of calling the CUDA code from your Web app and then simply return the results to the client who made the request.

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for tutorials for how to do this, but could not find anything. If someone could point me in the right direction I'll be very happy. I know there is a node.js plugin for cuda that can be used when the frontend and cudo-code runs on the same server. I'll investigate if it is possible to call a Amazon cluster instead. That would be cool.

Comment: As far as tutorial to go off, this is very dependent on how you are designing your application.  Make sure you are not confusing the applicability of the library you mentioned (the ability to execute CUDA commands from a scripting langage is the same as executing a program written in CUDA from a scripting language, well one is a superset of the other).

Comment: Running a CUDA program in a cluster such that you are running your program across multiple GPU instances requires a fair amount of technical knowledge and require you to design an effective way of managing communication between your program handeling requests and your CUDA program.  Consider starting by simply calling your cuda program via a _shell command_ using what ever server side scripting language you are using to handle requests.  ([here](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs) is a link to a nodejs example.)

Comment: Also, if I have sufficiently answered your question, consider accepting my answer...